# SUM and AVERAGE of multiple colums with TIME and INT as data type

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is my query and results, I also added below what I am trying to achieve.

UPH stands for 'Units Per Hour'

```
SELECT  
  TimeLog.ID
 ,TimeLog.DeptCode AS 'DC'
 ,TimeLog.OpCode AS 'OC'
 ,TimeLog.StartTime AS 'Start'
 ,TimeLog.FinishTime AS 'Finish'
 ,ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime),0)) 
 ,TimeLog.Units
 ,UPH = cast(isnull(Units / nullif(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime)*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
FROM dbo.TimeLog INNER JOIN dbo.AssociateInfo WITH (NOLOCK)
ON AssociateInfo.ID = TimeLog.ID
WHERE TimeLog.DeptCode = 'FB' AND TimeLog.OpCode = 'PU' AND TimeLog.Units IS NOT NULL

ID      DC  OC  Start       Finish      ElapsedTime Units   UPH
2375935 FB  PU  10:36:00    14:20:00    03:44:00    263     70
11259   FB  PU  03:15:00    04:00:00    00:45:00    100     133
11259   FB  PU  04:00:00    05:00:00    01:00:00    150     150
11259   FB  PU  05:15:00    06:00:00    00:45:00    50      67
11259   FB  PU  06:00:00    07:00:00    01:00:00    88      88
11259   FB  PU  07:40:00    08:00:00    00:20:00    77      231
11259   FB  PU  08:00:00    09:00:00    01:00:00    88      88
```

I would like to see results showing a total sum of ElapsedTime, Units and UPH where the ID, DC, and OC columns have the same values.

```
ID       DC    OC    ElapsedTime    Units    UPH
2375935  FB    PU    03:44:00       263      70
11259    FB    PU    04:50:00       816      169
```

Comment: use GROUP BY clause

Comment: sql has a sum function.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @DanBracuk Hi Dan, I have tried sum function and did not get what I was looking for, I may have been using incorrectly as well... I forgot to mention I am relatively new to SQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  
    TimeLog.ID
  , TimeLog.DeptCode AS 'DC'
  , TimeLog.OpCode AS 'OC'
  --, TimeLog.StartTime AS 'Start'
  --, TimeLog.FinishTime AS 'Finish'
  --, ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0)) 
  /* for greater than 24 hours: */
 , ElapsedTime = right('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,Start,Finish)) / 3600 )),2) + ':' 
               + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,Start,Finish)) / 60) % 60 ),2) + ':' 
               + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,Start,Finish)) % 60 )),2)
  , Units = sum(TimeLog.Units)
  , UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
FROM dbo.TimeLog 
  INNER JOIN dbo.AssociateInfo WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON AssociateInfo.ID = TimeLog.ID
WHERE TimeLog.DeptCode = 'FB'
  and TimeLog.OpCode   = 'PU'
  and TimeLog.Units IS NOT NULL
group by 
    TimeLog.ID
  , TimeLog.DeptCode
  , TimeLog.OpCode
```

rextester demo using your query output: http://rextester.com/IZZX78524

returns:

```
+---------+----+----+-------------+-------+-----+
|   ID    | DC | OC | ElapsedTime | Units | UPH |
+---------+----+----+-------------+-------+-----+
| 2375935 | fb | pu | 03:44:00    |   263 |  70 |
|   11259 | fb | pu | 04:50:00    |   553 | 114 |
+---------+----+----+-------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'dbo.TimeLog.Units' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ID       DC OC ElapsedTime Units UPH
    11259       FB PU 09:40:00         1369 142
    2375935    FB PU 03:44:00          263          70

Comment: @DRUIDRUID I would guess the join to `AssociateInfo` (not sure why this is even here) is duplicating rows from `TimeLog` because the elapsed time is exactly double.

Comment: I just remove the 'join' and the return is the same

Comment: @DRUIDRUID Then I guess you have `1369` units for id `11259` now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145738/discussion-between-druidruid-and-sqlzim).

Comment: when I use `ElapsedTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))` to show elapsed time of multiple rows and time is more than 24 hours the result is incorrect. How could we allow more than 24 in the HH space. I have changed `StartTime` and `FinishTime` to varchar....any advice

Comment: @DRUIDRUID I have updated my answer and the rextester demo to include how to show intervals that exceed 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tl.ID, tl.DeptCode AS DC, tl.OpCode AS OC,
       ElapsedTime = convert(time(0), dateadd(second, sum(datediff(second, StartTime, FinishTime)), 0)) ,
       SUM(tl.Units) as units,
       UPH = cast(coalesce(Units / nullif(sum(datediff(minute, StartTime, FinishTime))*1.0, 0), 0.0) * 60  as decimal(10, 0) )
FROM dbo.TimeLog tl INNER JOIN
     dbo.AssociateInfo ai
     ON ai.ID = tl.ID
WHERE tl.DeptCode = 'FB' AND tl.OpCode = 'PU' AND tl.Units IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY tl.ID, tl.DeptCode, tl.OpCode;
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "tl.ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "tl.DeptCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "tl.OpCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "tl.Units" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "tl.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "tl.DeptCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "tl.OpCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tl.ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tl.DeptCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tl.OpCode" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "tl.Units" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
   SELECT  
      TimeLog.ID
     ,MAX(TimeLog.DeptCode) AS 'DC'
     ,MAX(TimeLog.OpCode) AS 'OC' 
     ,SUM( convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))) AS 'ElapsedTime' 
     ,SUM(TimeLog.Units) AS 'Units'
     ,(cast(isnull(sum(TimeLog.Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,TimeLog.StartTime,TimeLog.FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0)))AS 'UPH'
    FROM dbo.TimeLog 
    WHERE TimeLog.DeptCode = 'FB' AND TimeLog.OpCode = 'PU' AND TimeLog.Units IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY TimeLog.ID
```

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: Still getting this message                                                                                                Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Operand data type time is invalid for sum operator.